# MYSQL Trigger recursion avoidance

Tags: mysql

I have a general AFTER UPDATE trigger for my users table to check if a column has changed, and if so, call a stored procedure.

The problem is the stored procedure does some calculations and itself updates a field in users.

How do I avoid the recursion if my stored procedure updates the users table, which invokes the trigger, which again invokes the stored procedure?

Thanks!

Comment: Wondered that mysql allows it :-S

Answer (score 1, accepted):

MySQL doesn't let you disable triggers (without dropping and recreating them), but you have a couple of options:

1. Don't update the users table from within the procedure.
2. Add a field to the users that the procedure would set to a specific value on update. When the trigger sees that value for that field, don't call the procedure.
3. Use a global variable to accomplish the above (NOT connection safe - will disable triggers for all connections).

Comment: For #3, would be better to use a session variable (ie, `@var` instead of `@@var`). You can even use it in such a way that it turns off when it detects the recursion happened (ie, in the trigger and proc, guard the potentially recursive code in `IF IFNULL(@unique_recurse_var, 0) = 0 THEN SET @unique_recurse_var = 1; <do guarded operation>; ELSE SET @unique_recurse_var = 0; END IF;`). You probably want unittests to make sure the functality never breaks though.